# sql select query among 3 tables

Tags: sql, select, join, multiple-tables

I have three tables:

ITEMDISPLAYCOuNTS *this table stores who displayed which posts and howmanytimes

postid, count, whodisplayedid

POSTS *this table stores who posted what?

postid, whopostedid

ASPNET_USERS

userid, username

What I want at the end is who displayed whose post, and how many times, with usernames, not userids:

OUTPUT

UserNameWhoDisplayed, UserNameWhosePost, Count

I wrote the following code, but it is not functioning properly.

```
SELECT u1.UserName, u2.UserName, ItemDisplayCounts.Count
FROM ItemDisplayCounts AS i, Posts AS p, aspnet_Users AS u1, aspnet_Users AS u2
WHERE p.UserId = u2.UserId AND i.UserId = u1.UserId AND i.PostId = p.PostId
```

Can anyone suggest any corrections?

Comment: what does you mean by "not functioning properly"? What RDBMS do you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this (changed your joins to proper ANSI ones):

```
select
    iu.UserName as UserNameWhoDisplayed,
    pu.UserName as UserNameWhosePost,
    sum(i.Count) as [Count]
from ItemDisplayCounts as i
    inner join aspnet_Users as iu on iu.userid = i.whodisplayedid
    inner join posts as p on p.postid = i.postid
    inner join aspnet_Users as pu on pu.userid = p.whopostedid
group by
    iu.UserName,
    pu.UserName
```

Comment: I actually do not need sum() function.  I removed group by lines, and used only i.Count in the select statement. I guess this will be the same except that it will repeat the same UserNameWhoDisplayed couple of times.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly you do not need to perform any math in the query, since you have the `count` field in the `ITEMDISPLAYCOuNTS` table.  So, I do believe this will work for you:

```
SELECT U2.username AS UserNameWhoDisplayed, 
       U1.username AS UserNameWhosePost, 
       ID.[Count]
FROM ((POSTS AS P 
       INNER JOIN ASPNET_USERS AS U1 ON P.whopostedid = U1.userid) 
       INNER JOIN ITEMDISPLAYCOuNTS AS ID ON P.postid = ID.postid) 
       INNER JOIN ASPNET_USERS AS U2 ON ID.whodisplayedid = U2.userid
```